# If statement with a class pointer is causing a segfault

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, if-statement, segmentation-fault

I've made a finite state machine class for a little C++ project I'm working on, but for some reason, the program segfaults as soon as it gets to a certain if-statement.

Here is the class itself:

```
class FiniteStateMachine
{
protected:
    void cleanup();

    State* state_;

public:
    FiniteStateMachine();
    FiniteStateMachine( State* const state );
    ~FiniteStateMachine();

    void changeState();
    void forceState( State* const state );
    char const* getStateName();

};
```

And here in the definition, the program segfaults as soon as it gets to the conditional statement:

```
void FiniteStateMachine::changeState()
{
    debugging("FiniteStateMachine::changestate() called");

    if( state_ ) // problem point
    {
        debugging("state_ is not nullptr");
        // state_.handle();
    }
    else
    {
        debugging("state_ is nullptr");
    }
}
```

debugging() is just a function used to display messages to stdout while in debug mode. The strangest thing to me is that if( state_ ) is used earlier in the program without a hitch.

I'm using gcc version 4.9.2, Linux Mint 17.2, and C++11

If you need any further details, [here is the link to the github repository.](https://github.com/NickDave/Wildlife)

Comment: This suggests the `this` pointer is null inside that function, which means you've invoked the member function on a non-existent object.

Comment: What if state isn't `nullptr` and also isn't a valid address? Two examples: an uninitialized pointer and being used after `state_` has been destroyed?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] as you are told in the How To Ask.

Comment: @user4581301, that is technically undefined behaviour, but in practice simply loading an uninitialized pointer to test if it is null won't segfault on most modern hardware (it would have to be a trap representation to crash there). It is far more likely when `if (this->state_)` crashes that the invalid pointer is `this` not `state_`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Have to agree with that. Dangerous in the future, but not crash-worthy here.

Comment: @user4581301, it's only dangerous if it really can be invalid, which you can't know because you can't see the constructors, so it's just idle speculation and not related to this question.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The posted FiniteStateMachine definition is not going to pass the Rule of Three. May or may not be a problem in Charles' implementation, but should be brought to his attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root of your problem is that your Engine::getInstance method has a bug.

```
Engine* Engine::getInstance()
{
    Engine* instance = instance_;

    if( !instance_ )
    {
        instance_ = new Engine;
    }

    return instance;
}
```

The first time this method is called you will always return null.  You should remove the local Engine variable and just work with the instance_ member.

```
Engine* Engine::getInstance()
{
    if( !instance_ )
    {
        instance_ = new Engine;
    }

    return instance_;
}
```

This should fix the null pointer which is causing the crash on the if statement

Comment: Alternative (albeit pointlessly) `Engine*& instance = instance_;` would also have worked.